Identify show/episode where man was afraid of insects?
I recall seeing either an Outer Limits or Twilight Zone episode (could be something else though) where a man was deathly afraid of insects (cockroaches?). Throughout the episode he was seen cleaning him apartment (lab/basement?) and killing any insects that he would find. By the end of the episode it was revealed that he was made of cockroaches (or was a cockroach?).
The episode was made in either the 1950s or 1960s and it was black and white. 

Might be the Creepshow episode 'They're Creeping on You'.

 At the end he becomes infested with them and could seem as if he was made of them. 

A synopsis of the episode is at the following link. It was the 5th episode:



